How to install R 3.6 with gfortran compiler on MacBook M3?
I have two versions of R on my Macbook, R 4.4 and R 3.6. The fortran compiler from [https://mac.r-project.org/tools/] is installed. R 4.4 works fine and can use the gfortran to install several packages.
However, I have a difficult time to make the gfortan work for R 3.6. One problem I ran into is: after setting FLIBS =  -L/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0 in the R Makeconf file, when installing the glmnet  package that uses gfortran in R 3.6, I received the following error:
ld: warning: ignoring file '/private/var/folders/wc/8k8lg3dd7mvcvj5zfch921300000gp/T/Rtmp9AzvoR/R.INSTALL363b114fb21a/glmnet/src/wls.o': found architecture 'arm64', required architecture 'x86_64'
Has anyone successfully installed an old version of R such as R 3.6 with gfortan on Mac with arm64 architecture?
Thank you very much!
I have also tried to create the Makeovars file inside the .R folder and set the FC, F77, and FLIBS variables, but it didn't work.

CRAN did not start releasing binaries for Apple silicon until R 4.1, so I wouldn't hold out hope.

Hi @MikaelJagan, Thank you for your reply! This is perhaps the reason why I had the error message.

Creating an osx-64 environment using conda works perfectly. See related discussions in this link.
